# How to iterate multiple regex's?

Tags: regex, perl, hash, replace, file-handling

So to start out I'm having trouble with making my code cleaner, I know logically it's a mess but I'm relatively new. Anyways heres what we're working with:

```
 sub Regexin    {

        open (my $in, "<", "regexin.txt") or die "cannot open: $!";
        open (my $out, ">", "regexin1.txt") or die "cannot open: $!";
        while (<$in>)
        {
        s/#Location/$EmergInfo[0]/g;
        s/#LastUpdate/$EmergInfo[1]/g;
        s/#AddInfo/$EmergInfo[2]/g;
        s/#SpecInst/$EmergInfo[3]/g;
        s/#MsdsLoc/$EmergInfo[4]/g;
        s/#SpillLoc/$EmergInfo[5]/g;
        s/#CONTACT1/$EmergInfo[6]/g;
        s/#CONTACT2/$EmergInfo[7]/g;
        s/#DEPARTMENT1/$EmergInfo[8]/g;
        s/#DEPARTMENT2/$EmergInfo[9]/g;
        s/#OFFICE1/$EmergInfo[10]/g;
        s/#OFFICE2/$EmergInfo[11]/g;
        s/#OPHONE1/$EmergInfo[12]/g;
        s/#OPHONE2/$EmergInfo[13]/g;
        s/#HPHONE1/$EmergInfo[14]/g;
        s/#HPHONE2/$EmergInfo[15]/g;
print $out $_;
        }
        close $in;
        close $out;
        unlink('regexin.txt') or die "error deleting regexin.txt\n";
                }
```

All of those regexes are obviously really gross looking and I've experimented with using foreach and each with hashes and multiple ways using arrays but haven't come to a nice one line.
My goal is to get something like this:

```
s/$keys/$values/g;
```

Just that and it iterates but regex's are weird. Also the variable $EmergInfo just holds text (stuff like phone numbers and names). I've really scoured the internet (perldoc included) but definitely could've missed a few things. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where does `$EmergInfo` come from? Your data looks better suited for a hash (or hashes), so if you have control over the creation of `$EmergInfo`, I would do something more like: `my %info = ( location => 'foo', home_phone => 'bar' ); my %mapping = ( '#Location' => 'location', '#HPHONE1' => 'home_phone'); foreach my $placeholder (keys %info) { $line =~ s/$placeholder/$mapping{$placeholder}/g; }`

Comment: EmergInfo is information inputted via online form. How would you get the lines its reading assigned to $line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you organize your EmergInfo data in a hash instead of an array, you will be able to search and replace all fields at once.

```
my %EmergInfo = (
  Location => 'New York',
  LastUpdate => 'Feb 17, 2015',
  OPHONE1 => '800-555-1212',
  etc => '...',
);

my $joined_keys = join('|', keys %EmergInfo);
my $regexp = qr/#($joined_keys)/;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/$regexp/$EmergInfo{$1}/g;
  print;
}

__DATA__
#Location
#LastUpdate
#AddInfo
#SpecInst
#OPHONE1
```

EDIT: note that I'm creating the compiled regular expression once outside the while loop so that it doesn't have to be created for each iteration within the loop.

Comment: It worked and worked well, a few questions though. What does joining the keys do? I thought $1 wasn't good to use because of the many issues it has with it. Also from $regexp what does this variable do and why do i need it? Thanks a bunch for the help EDIT: also why the literal pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will walk you through it. You want to seed a hash with the key values and then walk through each making the substitution. You should be able to modify this code to fit your needs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %info;

sub Regexin {
    open (my $in, "<", "regexin.txt") or die "cannot open: $!";
    open (my $out, ">", "regexin1.txt") or die "cannot open: $!";
    while (<$in>)
    {
    for my $k (keys %info) {
        s/#$k/$info{$k}/g;
    }
    print $out $_;
    }
    close $in;
    close $out;
    #unlink('regexin.txt') or die "error deleting regexin.txt\n";
}

my @EmergInfo=('Home', 'Today');

%info=('Location'=>$EmergInfo[0],
      'LastUpdate'=>$EmergInfo[1]);

Regexin();
```